# Newbie scala confused about identiy type signature, and nothing (bottom)

Tags: scala

I'm best described as a C#/F# + a bit of amateur Haskell programmer.

I'm a bit confused about the type signatures in Scala.

for example

the identity function has type

```
Nothing => Nothing
```

(according to scala console in my intellij thing)

but to me that makes no sense.

the type of identity is something like..

```
all x . x => x
```

.....

so

```
identity 1
=> x ~ Int 
=> 1 : Int

Nothing => Nothing
```

makes no sense to me....I would expect I type exception when passing any value to a function expecting Nothing!

clearly Im missing something.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "the identity function"? There is no identity function in the Scala standard library. Where did it come from? How is it defined? Note: there is an [`identity` *method* (not function) in the Scala standard library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#identity[A](x:A):A), with type signature `def identity[A](x: A): A` and [the implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L185) is `@inline def identity[A](x: A): A         = x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In scala there is a distinction between methods and function values. Methods can be parameterized, while values (function or otherwise) can not.

So the identity method looks like this:

```
def identity[A](x: A): A = x
```

It has type `[A](x: A)A`. But if you convert it to a function value like this:

```
val idFunction = identity _
```

The value `idFunction` will have type `Nothing => Nothing`. Since I didn't provide a type argument to `identity` the compiler inferred `A = Nothing`.

What you can do is this:

```
val intIdentity = identity[Int] _
```

And then `intIdentity` will have type `Int => Int`.

Comment: hmmmmm but "Nothing => Nothing" is a very odd thing to infer...it seems clearly "wrong"

Comment: let me post another question....to get my head around this, about what I actually want to write

Answer (score 1):

The `identity` function is defined in `scala.PreDef` and has the following type signature:

```
def identity[A](x: A): A
```

It takes a type parameter `A`, a value of type `A`, and returns what it got as an input.

See the docs for scala.PreDef here: [scala.Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html)

Comment: That's not the identity function, that's the identity method. Since it seems at least likely that the OP is confusing methods and functions, and that this confusion plays a significant role in their question, I think it is not exactly helpful to further perpetrate this confusion. There are enough *questions* in the [tag:scala] tag on [so] where the OP is confused about the difference between methods and functions, so let's not start adding *answers* that add to this confusion as well.

Comment: Wow... Such a rant because I seemingly got one single word wrong? You know you could just edit it?